# C++ Using a reference function from header file in the cpp?

Tags: c++, reference

I have a header file and a cpp file. In the `.h` file I declared a class and a function with returning a reference:

**`.h` file**:

```
#include <iostream>
class testclass {
    Car &createCar(int x, int y);
}
```

**`.cpp` file**:

```
#include<testclass.h>
Car testclass:&createCar(int x, int y)
{
  ....
}
```

But when I try to access the function in the `.cpp` file I get an error:

> Declaration is not compatible

Comment: You use `CarClass &` in the header and `Car` in the .cpp file

Comment: Thank you for the information, this was a typing mistake! Sorry!

Comment: Well, *two* typing mistakes, then - both the type and the misplaced `&`

Comment: Also note that `#include <testclass.h>` implies that your header is in the system include path.  If you want to search the current directory, use `#include "testclass.h"`

Comment: Note that 1) your function is not public; 2) I hope you are knowing what you're doing when you return a reference, since there are many risks associated with this practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.h` file, `&` is not a reference to a function.  The `&` is part of the function's return type.  So, the function actually returns a reference to a `Car` instance.  It would help you to understand it if you actually write it that way:

```cpp
Car& createCar(int x, int y);
```

As such, in the `.cpp` file, you need to move the `&` to the return type to match the declaration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class testclass {
    Car& createCar(int x, int y);
};
```

```cpp
#include "testclass.h"

Car& testclass::createCar(int x, int y)
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The function definition in .cpp file should be compatible with its decleration in .h file so modify it as follows.

.cpp file:

```
#include"testclass.h"
Car& testclass::createCar(int x, int y)
{
  ....
}
```

Note that I modified `<testclass.h>` to `"testclass.h"`. use the brackets only with the built in headers.

Follow the following line if you want to know why you should use `"testclass.h"` instead of `<testclass.h>` and which one of them you should use  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: A bit more explanation might be nice, code dumps without explanation are rarely useful.

Comment: @anonymous, note the OP fixed the typo for the return type.

Comment: @anonymous "*use the brackets only with the built in headers*" - more accurately, use `<>` for any header whose path is relative to the project's header file search paths, which includes system headers.  Use `""` for any header whose path is relative to the source file currently being compiled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think he is very beginner so I think what I said is convenient so far.

Comment: @anonymous better for the OP to learn it now rather than later, and why it works the way it does.

Comment: Keep in mind the use of the two variations of `#include` are *guidelines,* all the standard states is that the locations of the headers is implementation defined. The actual guideline (in the standard) is to use `<>` for headers provided by the implementation, nothing to do with where they live in the filesystem (indeed, they don't even *have* to exist as real files). See `C++20 [cpp.include]`.